# What could cause an air data computer interfaced via A429 to only display integer values?

Tags: avionics, arinc-429, air-data-computer

I'm working with a Shadin 2000 air data computer interfaced via ARINC 429 to an Avidyne IFD 550. For some reason, the airspeed tape is flipping between discreet values, and not gradually increasing/decreasing. This makes the readout appear very ratchety or jumpy.

I'm by no means an expert on troubleshooting these kinds of problems. What could be causing this?

Comment: Check the message format expected by the 550.  Verify That the 2000 is encoding in that format and verify that the expected data is being sent.  You’ll need a bus analyzer.

Comment: I don’t see the 2000 on this list: https://pilotsupport.avidyne.com/kb/article/433-ifd5xx-4xx-compatible-equipment/

Comment: Interesting- the configuration setting for it is shown in the Installation Manual: https://imgur.com/a/KVT7DM4

Comment: Well, good. I wouldn’t trust info you randomly find on the internet ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what rate the IFD 550 expects the transmit rate to be, but from what I can find on the Shadin 2000, it's label transmit rate is configured by a switch position and can vary from 50,100, or 200 ms, which longer periods could cause a jumpy display if it isn't filtering the received label at all.